# Name of this $u\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=x_{1}+\alpha x_{2}+\beta \sqrt{x_{1} x_{2}}$ utility function?

Tags: utility

I have seen this $u\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=x_{1}+\alpha x_{2}+\beta \sqrt{x_{1} x_{2}}$ a numbers of time now. I wonder whether it is somehow special and therefore has it's own name?

Kind regards,

Comment: Latex doesn’t format in question titles fyi

Comment: "LaTeX doesn't format", what does that mean? Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: disregard my comment, LaTeX doesn't appear in titles properly on the mobile version

Comment: For $\alpha=\beta^2/4$ it is additively separable, but other than that I wouldn't know any special property or even name for it.

Comment: @VARulle " additively separable" What does that mean?

Comment: See here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/meaning-of-additively-separable-linear-in-x