# What are the fundamental economic proofs

Tags: mathematical-economics

We had a question on this site for  [Fundamental equations in economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/35/fundamental-equations-in-economics). What I'd like to know is what are the most important proofs needed in economics?

Comment: I think a fundamental series of proofs are the separating hyperplane theorem, the supporting hyperplane theorem, and then using them (and fixed-pointe theorems) to prove the first and second welfare theorems. 

Also, proving the existence of equilibria.

Comment: How is this different from asking for the fundamental *theorems* in economics? Is the emphasis on *proofs* supposed to mean something, like conceptually sophisticated or technically challenging?

Answer (score 2):

I would say the following four:

- Nash Equilibrium via Fixed Point (either Kakutani, Brouwer or Tarski, depending on the problem);
- Welfare theorems via Hanh-Banach theory (mainly the separating hyperplane theorem);
- Utility and Profit Optimization via Weierstrass Theorem, Kuhn-Tucker conditions, and existence of a Lagrangian;
- Minimization of Least Squares;